# Do you like the automated posting of Meta questions to the chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

In case you didn't know, emacs.SE has a web-based [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17392/emacs).

It is a little different than other chat mechanisms that you may be familiar with.  The difference most striking to me is that past messages posted when you aren't present are visible to you.

There is a bot in the room named Emacs Meta.  The only thing it does is post links to questions from Emacs Meta into the room.  You can see what I mean by visiting the chat room.

I hate the bot and I want it to go away.

How do you feel about it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kill the bot.

Actually, first identify the owner of the room, then politely ask him or her to kill the bot.

Comment: There is currrently no owner. Any moderator on any SE site is a moderator in chat and can configure the feeds. In a few days we'll have site mods who're responsible for managing chat rooms associated with this site. I set it up initially, a lot of sites do that so that people can keep up with new meta questions without having to keep a tab open. If this thread concludes that we don't like the bot, A by-then-appointed mod or I or any other SE mod can turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

No, keep the bot.

It serves some valuable purpose and doesn't drown out conversation.

Comment: With about one post per day, the bot can't decently be said to “drown out conversation”.

Comment: That's higher than the rate of posts by humans.  And each bot-post is physically larger.

Answer (score -1):

Take the third way and change the question feed into a drop down ticker like so: [image: example of EL&U chatroom with question ticker decended]

Comment: Hm, a third option!  Let's call this one 'Maim' and the others 'Kill' and 'Keep'.  Ok, here's an example of what 'maim' would look like: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18601/drop-down-ticker-test  ...I am neutral on it.  I would vote for kill or maim, but not keep.

Comment: Ticker feeds are incredibly annoying, but [fortunately they can be hidden with a userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115224/can-i-silence-ticker-feeds-in-a-chat-room).